# Mustek 1200 CU Plus Scanner Ubuntu 18.04/ linux mint 19.3 driver

Tags: drivers, files, scanner, deb

In order t get my old Mustek 1200 CU Plus Scanner to work on Ubuntu 18.04, I had to download 2 files (PS1Dfw.usb / SBSfw.usb) from http://www.meier-geinitz.de/sane/gt68xx-backend/ and copy them manually to:
/usr/share/sane/gt68xx/
then tried to scan, but that didnt work and so I unplugged and replugged in the scanner to get the job done.

Is there a simpler way to do this, like a .deb file or something?

Comment: what is your OS? Ubuntu or mint?

Comment: I run both mint and ubuntu